# JAVA Custom Annotation: Restricting annotation parameters on certain condition

Tags: java, enums, java-annotations

I'm starting to learn java annotation and I want to use this as some sort of Generator label. I want to generate random texts only, numbers only or text and numbers.

Here is my custom annotation:

```
public @interface RandomGenerator {

    public int length() default 5;

    public GeneratorTypeEnum type();

    public GeneratorCaseTypeEnum caseType() default GeneratorCaseTypeEnum.TO_LOWER_AND_UPPER;

}
```

So far so good. I'm using enum to provide some extra definition if used by client. Here is the init:
I have a Class to use the annotation

```
public class Employee {

    @RandomGenerator(type = GeneratorTypeEnum.NUMBERS_ONLY, caseType = GeneratorCaseTypeEnum.TO_LOWER_AND_UPPER)
    private String id;

    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}
```

But as you can see, I can use the `GeneratorTypeEnum.NUMBERS_ONLY` WITH `caseType GeneratorCaseTypeEnum.TO_LOWER_AND_UPPER` which is obviously not good because there are no upper or lower case numbers.

**Enums:**

**GeneratorTypeEnum**

```
public enum GeneratorTypeEnum {
    TEXT_AND_NUMBERS,
    NUMBERS_ONLY, 
    TEXT_ONLY
}
```

**GeneratorCaseTypeEnum**

```
public enum GeneratorCaseTypeEnum {
    TO_LOWER, 
    TO_UPPER, 
    TO_LOWER_AND_UPPER
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to restrict parameters in annotation?
2. If false for question #1, can you give your theory or opinion and if those are not beginner friendly, can you please provide some links for references.

Answers will be very much appreciated.

PS: I feel bad because I can't give any of my trial and error solutions as I am a beginner.